# Generating Pythagorean Triples S.T. $b = a+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, triangles

I am looking for a method to generate [Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) $(a,b,c)$. There are [many methods listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) but I have a unique constraint that I can't seem to integrate into any of the listed methods.

I need to generate Pythagorean Triples $(a,b,c)$ such that:

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
$$a\lt b\lt c \,; \quad a,b,c \in \Bbb Z^+$$
$$and $$
$$b=a+1$$

Is there a way to modify one of the listed methods to include this constraint?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to tag this question, so please re-tag if necessary!

Comment: $\large a = 3,\quad b = 4,\quad c = 5$,

Comment: Your $a$ could be odd or even. Two different results: When $a$ is odd, triplet is $(3,4,5)$,  $(119,120,169)$, or  $(4059,4060,5741)$; When $a$ is even, only triplet I can think about is $(20,21,29)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We give a way to obtain all solutions. It is not closely connected to the listed methods. However, the recurrence we give at the end can be expressed in matrix form, so has a structural connection with some methods in your linked list.

We want $2a^2+2a+1$ to be a perfect square $z^2$. Equivalently, we want $4a^2+4a+2=2z^2$, that is $(2a+1)^2-2z^2=-1$.

This is a **Pell equation**. One can give a recurrence for the solutions. One can also give a closed form that has a similar shape to the Binet closed form for the Fibonacci numbers.

**Added:** We can for example get all solutions by expressing $(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}$, where $n$ is an integer, in the form $s+t\sqrt{2}$, where $s$ and $t$ are integers. Then $z=t$ and $2a+1=s$.

One can get a closed form from this by noting that $(1-\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}=s-t\sqrt{2}$. That gives us 
$$s=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1} + (1-\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}}{2}.$$
There is a similar formula for $t$.

**Remark:** The following recurrence is probably more useful than the closed form.

If $(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}=s_n+t_n\sqrt{2}$, then $(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+3}=s_{n+1}+t_{n+1}\sqrt{2}$, where 
$$s_{n+1}=3s_n+4t_n,\qquad t_{n+1}=2s_n+3t_n.$$

This will let you quickly compute the first dozen or so solutions (the numbers grow fast). We start with $n=0$, which gives a degenerate triangle. For $n=1$, we get $s_1=7$, $t_1=5$, which gives the $(3,4,5)$ triangle. We get $s_2=41, t_2=29$, giving the triple $(20,21,29)$. And so on.

Comment: Could you link me to information regarding `"the Binet closed form for the Fibonacci numbers?"`

Comment: OK, [here it is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) But maybe the material I am adding will help also.

Comment: Thanks for all the great information! You have given me some new topics to learn about!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's there in the special cases section as [*Almost-isosceles Pythagorean triple*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Almost-isosceles_Pythagorean_triples), or when the non-hypotenuse sides differ by 1. The complete formula is,

$$\Big(\frac{x-1}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{x+1}{2}\Big)^2=y^2\tag{1}$$

where $x,y$ are solutions to the *Pell equation*,

$$x^2-2y^2 = -1\tag{2}$$

Since from $(2)$ one can tell that $x$ is always odd, then the terms of $(1)$ are integers.

Answer (score 1):

To produce Pythagorean triples where $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $b = a + 1$

Start with $n = 1$

$\sqrt{n(1 + \sqrt{2})^4}$

Round this down to an integer, then square it.  This gets you $c^2$, which is $25$, so $c = 5$. Now take $c$ and divide it by $\sqrt{2}$.  $\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$, rounded to the nearest half, is $3.5$. $a$ and $b$ are the integers on either side of $3.5$.

Now repeat the process with $n = c^2$, to be precise, $n = 25$:

$\sqrt{25(1 + \sqrt{2})^4}$ rounded down, squared, makes $841$, so $c = 29$.  $\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$ rounded to the nearest half is $20.5$, so $a = 20, b = 21$

Again, repeat with $n = 841$ and keep repeating as long as you like, and you will find all of the infinite Pythagorean triples where $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $b = a + 1$

Here's a really big one I found:

$a = 666554398276487455279750313289061631639$

$b = 666554398276487455279750313289061631640$

$c = 942650270102046130733437746596776286089$

I don't know if this is the kind of answer you were looking for, but I thought I'd share my method anyway.

Regards,

Josiah Hamilton

Edit: I had written "rounded to the nearest integer" but it was supposed to say "rounded DOWN ..."